# Apps run as root appearing like win 98 style after installation of gnome 3

Tags: gnome, gtk

I installed Gnome 3 using Ricotz's PPA. Then all windows using `sudo` and `gksu` is looking like its running under windows 98.
System Specs:

> Intel Core 2 duo
>
> Nvidia 6200
>
> Ubuntu 11.04

I also installed the Adwance theme.

Comment: I don't see GNOME3 in any of ricotz's PPAs, can you edit your question to be more specific as to which PPA you're using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to this is to fix the gtk2 theme to do that:

- Click activities
- Type in appearance
- Click the first result

and in themes, select Ambiance instead of Adwance

Now this should be fixed